# How to call findPreference from the main activity, dialog's onClick function?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialog

I have the following dialog in main activity:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    final Dialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_NAME:
        builderDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_text))
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_share_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // how should I call findPreference here?
                       PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("pref_key");
                       ...
                   }
               })
```

I am getting the following error:

> The method findPreference(String) is undefined for the type new
>   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call this using your context;

```
YourActivity.this.findPreference("pref_key");
```

that should work ;)

Comment: What should I use as `YourActivity`? Is is name of my main activity? Then it doesn't work: _The method findPreference(String) is undefined for the type MyActivity_. MyActivity extends ListActivity: _public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {_.

Comment: then create a local variable in your activity:
Context mContext;
and in the onCreate, do: mContext=getBaseContext();

then in your dialog use mContext.findPreference("pref_key");

Comment: @SebastianBreit--I have declared `Context mContext` and in `onCreate` I have `mContext = getBaseContext();` but I don't have a `Dialog`. If I put `mContext.findPreference("key");` in `onCreate, I get 'Cannot resolve findPreference(String)`